# React styled-components shared styles

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I have a question about both directory structure and the technique of sharing styles when using `styled-components` in react.

I have a `Project` and `Task` page. They both contain different information, but they are displayed in kinda the same way.

Example:

```
const Foo = styled.div`
  margin: 30px !important;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-width: 700px;
  min-height: 800px;
`;
```

This is a styled component that I would use as a parent div for both of them. So I can do create `const Task = styled.div` and `const Project = styled.div` and copy  this style to each of them (they are in different folders of course). But then if I want to change something, this becomes painful, because I have to make changes in multiple places.

My directory structure is as follows:

- `src`

  - `components`

    - `Navbar`

      - `index.js`
      - `Navbar.tsx`
      - `styles.tsx`
  - `containers`

    - `Task`
    - `Project`

`Task` and `Project` also contain 3 files, like `Navbar`. So here are my questions:

1. Where do I define a shared style like `Foo`? Is it `src/components/shared`, `src/components/shared/styles` or maybe `src/shared/stylees`?
2. No matter where I put it, how should I define this shared style? Because I can think of two options:

Option 1:

Create a `styled.div` like I've shown above and just use it as it is, so for example:

```
const Project = () => {
  return <Foo>{content}</Foo>
}
```

Option 2:

Create a `css` instance (?) like this:

```
const Foo = css`
  margin: 30px !important;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-width: 700px;
  min-height: 800px;
`
```

And then use it like this (so I would define a new styled component for `Task` and `Project` and include this style I defined):

```
const StyledProject = styled.div`
  ${Foo}
`

const Project = () => {
  return <StyledProject>{content}</StyledProject>
}
```

`styled-components` docs show how to define styled components for a current component that I am working on. I also found some conventions about that and I chose the `index.js/<component_name>.tsx/styles.tsx` trio, but there are many more. However, I couldn't really find docs/article about what to do with shared styles like this.

Do you guys know the way, or maybe you can share your particular approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me, when I think about shared styles I think about *why* are the styles being shared. Do my two components appear similar because they are actually variations of a higher level component, and if so, what is that component?

For example, perhaps both `Task` and `Project` are supposed to look like "cards". In this case, I'd argue that what we have is actually the beginning of a new component called `Card` which will encapsulate the shared styling and just be another component.

```
const Project = () => {
    return <Card>{content}</Card>
}
```

In other words, instead of thinking about sharing *styles*, I prefer thinking about sharing *components*. Mentally it's the difference between making things look like cards and, in some sense, *printing* content onto cards.

Besides fitting organically within the structure you already have, it's also flexible in that cards can eventually become more structured without duplication at the usage sites.

So to answer your questions more specifically:

1. I suppose I'd make a component in `src/components/NameOfComponent`
2. And I would make the standard trio of files (`index.js`, `NameOfComponent.tsx`, and `styles.tsx`), though if at first the component is as simple as a single styled div, I might bypass `styles.tsx` and put the styled-components definition directly into `NameOfComponent.tsx`.

When it comes to frontend development, there never is one right way to do things, just a collection of generally good practices. So what I wrote above is also not the one-right-way, but my opinion having worked on different projects.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. This is my first try at web dev and it kinda overwhelmed me with the number of choices I can make. I am a perfectionist in some sense and I always subconsciously try to find the "one true way" to do stuff. Your approach is good, I've basically done my structure exactly as you described. One last thing: separating components vs separating styles - so even if my let's say `Card` is only a `styled.div`, nothing special, no states, no props - basically not a React component, you still put it in `src/components` along with other actual components? You don't separate them, right?

Comment: Yep! Because even though it's just styles, I think of it like a component.

Comment: Thanks! I guess I'll just wait a little more for maybe some more input, if nothing comes I'll of course accept your answer.